# How to reference a shadowed variable in the superclass of a superclass?

Tags: java, inheritance

This is a simple example of inheritance where there is a shadowed variable x.

```
class A{
    int x=1;
}
class B extends A{
    int x=2;
}
class C extends B{
    int x=3;
    int y;
}
```

How can I reference the shadowed variable x of class A in class C?(I want something like `y=super.super.x;` that works well.)

Comment: You do realize those variables are private right?

Comment: @kervin Package private.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not as hard as you might think. (While I strongly encourage avoiding this situation,) if you have a class `C` that inherits from class `B`, which in turn inherits from class `A`, all of which implement a public field `x`, then using `super` is usually the wrong way to go about it.

Instead, given class `C`, try this:

```
((A)this).x;   //don't forget the parentheses!
```

that will give you the value of `x` for `A`. Also,

```
super.x == ((B)this).x;
```

which is generally why, for single steps, we usually just use `super`.

Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge, there is no way to achieve this the way you imagine. Your best bet would be to implement an access method in your class `B`:

```
class B extends A{
    int x=2;

    protected int getXFromA() {
        return super.x;
    }
}
```

This way you would be able to access the value of `x` as defined in class `A` from class `C`.

I would be very interested in your use case, though. Considering object oriented design, what reason could there be to directly access `A`'s members from `C`? If this is the case, from an OOP perspective, `C` could not really be considered a proper subclass of `B` anymore.

Answer (score 1):

```
class A {
    int x = 1;
}
class B extends A {
    int x = 2;
}
class C extends B {
    int x = 3;
    int y = ((A) this).x;
}
```

Note that shadowing is generally discouraged due to the confusion it can cause.